# JavaScript - How to get the specific data from a Promise

Tags: javascript, api, promise

So this is the situation: I'm trying to get specific data from a Promise. The Promise shows data from an API: https://api.covid19api.com/country/netherlands/status/confirmed

The Promise consists of three values (0, 1 and 2) and each value consists of an array which hold multiple variables. I want to get the data from the last variable in the array from the Promise names '0' (do you understand?).

This is what the Promise looks like:
[Here you can see it consists of the values 0, 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnN8B.png)

After clicking on it: [I try to get the data from the array (PromiseValue I believe it is called?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9WqV.png)

So this is the data I want: the data from the last variable in the array. From this variable I want the data from 'Cases', so '8603'. [This is the data I try to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3a00.png)

```js
function getAPIdata() {

  var url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/country';
  var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  var requestConfirmed = url + '/' + country + '/' + 'status' + '/' + 'confirmed';
  var requestRecovered = url + '/' + country + '/' + 'status' + '/' + 'recovered';
  var requestDeaths = url + '/' + country + '/' + 'status' + '/' + 'deaths';


  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  Promise.all([
    fetch(requestConfirmed, requestOptions),
    fetch(requestRecovered, requestOptions),
    fetch(requestDeaths, requestOptions)
  ])

    .then(function (responses) {
      return responses.map(function (response){
        if(!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
        return response.json();
      });

    }) .then(function(result){
        onAPISucces(result);
        // console.log(result);

    }) .catch(function (error){
        onAPIError(error);
    });

  }

  function onAPISucces(result) {

    var type = result;
    var landenLijst = result;
    console.log(landenLijst);
    var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
    // console.log(landenLijst[landenLijst.length - 1].Cases);
    for(var i=0; i < landenLijst.length; i++);
    // console.log(landenLijst[i].TotalConfirmed);

    var totaalAantalBesmettingen = landenLijst[0].PromiseValue[PromiseValue.length - 1];

    var totaleBesmettingen = document.getElementById('confirmedInformation');
    totaleBesmettingen.innerHTML = totaalAantalBesmettingen;

  }

  function onAPIError(error) {
    console.error('Oeps, foutje!', error);
    var totaleBesmettingen = document.getElementById('confirmedInformation');
    totaleBesmettingen.innerHTML = 'Please try again. Did you enter a country?';
  }

  document.getElementById('zoek').onclick = function(){
    getAPIdata();
  };
```

```html
<body>

      <form>
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose a country:</legend>
      <label for="country">Country:</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="For example: Belgium"/>
      <input type="button" id="zoek" value="Search" />
     </fieldset>
    </form>
      <p id="confirmedInformation"></p>
      <p id="recoveredInformation"></p>
      <p id="deathsInformation"></p>

      <p id="test"></p>

   </body>
```

I'm stuck at my code below (which you can find in my JavaScript code). I don't know how to get the specific data from the array. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

```
var totaalAantalBesmettingen = landenLijst[0].PromiseValue[PromiseValue.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pop the element from the array and access Cases property accordingly

See below:

```
 let data=result;
    let confirmed=data[0].pop();
    let recovered=data[1].pop();
    let deaths=data[2].pop();  
document.querySelector('#confirmedInformation').innerHTML="Confirmed:"+confirmed.Cases;
```

Run this code snippet.It will be interesting

```js
function getAPIdata() {
 // document.querySelector('span').classList.toggle('hidden');
  var url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/country';
  var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  var requestConfirmed = `${url}/${country}/status/confirmed`;
  var requestRecovered = `${url}/${country}/status/recovered`;
  var requestDeaths = `${url}/${country}/status/deaths`;
    Promise.all([
        fetch(requestConfirmed),
        fetch(requestRecovered),
        fetch(requestDeaths)
     ])
     .then(function (responses) {
       let jsonPromises=[];
       responses.forEach((response)=> jsonPromises.push(response.json()));
        return Promise.all(jsonPromises);
      })
     .then(function(result){
     // document.querySelector('span').classList.toggle('hidden');
        onAPISucces(result);
      }) 
      .catch(function (error){
      // document.querySelector('span').classList.toggle('hidden');
       console.log(error);
        onAPIError(error);
      });

  }
  function onAPISucces(result) {
    //console.log(result);
    let data=result;
    let confirmed=data[0].pop();
    let recovered=data[1].pop();
    let deaths=data[2].pop();  document.querySelector('#confirmedInformation').innerHTML="Confirmed:"+confirmed.Cases;  document.querySelector('#recoveredInformation').innerHTML="Recovered:"+recovered.Cases;  document.querySelector('#deathsInformation').innerHTML="Deaths:"+deaths.Cases;
    
  }
  function onAPIError(error) {
    console.error('Oeps, foutje!', error);
     document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML="Try again with valid country ";
     document.querySelector('#confirmedInformation').innerHTML="";  document.querySelector('#recoveredInformation').innerHTML="";  document.querySelector('#deathsInformation').innerHTML="";
  }

  document.getElementById('zoek').onclick = function(){
    getAPIdata();
  };
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <form>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Choose a country to get Coronavirus  update:</legend>
  <label for="country">Country:</label>
  <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="For example: NetherLands"/>
   <input type="button" id="zoek" onclick=" getAPIdata()" value="Search" />
   </fieldset>
    </form>
      <span>Data from API</span>
      <p id="confirmedInformation"></p>
      <p id="recoveredInformation"></p>
      <p id="deathsInformation"></p>
      <p id="test"></p>
   </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't know the answer was actually so complex. I have never worked with pop() and 'let', so I learned new things today. Thank you!

Comment: It's not complex. It's easy. See Pop will give you last object from array. Let is variable declaration same as var but it's scope is limited to block it's declared in. For example you declare in loop let v=o after loop you can't access v.. It gives undefined. Where as using var v=0  in loop you can access still variable v after loop... Got it..?

Comment: I get it now. Indeed, it is not that complex! Due to your clear explanation I understand your version of the code and the new things I learned today. Again, thank you for your help! I'm grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

`map` doesn't evaluate the promises from the `json()` call. You have to treat those as promises as well.

```
   // ...
   .then(function (responses) {
      return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response){
        if(!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
        return response.json();
      }));
   });
   // ...
```

Comment: You are right. I did not now this is possible. Thank you! :)